# Placebo tests in Synthetic Control Method

Tags: synthetic-data

I am trying to make graphs for the placebo tests under synthetic control, however I seem to be doing something wrong as I am not being able to merge the files. I am using the dataset of Abadie(2010) and using the command given under help synth to perform the placebo tests, however I am not sure on how to proceed.

If anyone can provide any useful help. :)

Thank you.

Comment: I am using Stata to run SCM analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Abadie, Diamond and Hainmueller wrote a paper (http://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/Paper/JSS2011.pdf) explaining how to implement the synthetic control method in R. Their explanation is much more detailed than the one you can find using Stata's help command. Moreover, their explanation also helps you to understand Stata's "synth" command.

In order to plot a placebo graph, we can use a "for loop" to estimate the "intervention effect" for each unit and, then, you can use a two-way graph to plot all the intervention effects in a single graph.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I've removed some pleasantries from your answer - it might seem impolite or impersonal, but we tend to keep things "to the point" here, so that future readers can find the information they want quickly. You might want to check out our [tour] if you haven't done so already.